# Open iOs settings with href link

Tags: html, ios, iphone, hyperlink, deep-linking

I have a web application that uses location, I would like to help the user enable location services if it is disabled on the device.

> To continue please : Enable **the Location Services** toggle.

This is what i tried :

```
  <a href="prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION">the Location Services</a>
```

Of course, I tried all possible schemes:

```
App-prefs://
App-prefs:
prefs://
prefs:
prefs:root
prefs:root=
```

But safari always tell me :

> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Comment: Prefs urls are considered private api. Safari will not open them

Comment: Any update, on how to open just Setting menu without submenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open a specific sub-menu in the settings due to Apple restrictions.

However you can open the main settings of an iPhone with this url:

```
App-Prefs://prefs:root
```

- Tested in IOS 16.
- Doesn't work on Mac.

Please note that according to Apple only the schemes explicitly documented are supported. Everything else is considered to be a private API.

⚠ The `App-Prefs` URL scheme is not documented for third-party use!

Comment: Not opening in safari

Comment: That does no longer work. Tested on iOS 16 / iPhone 14 Pro

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 17

Answer (score 1):

I tested in IOS 16 `<a href="App-Prefs://prefs:root"> Settings menu </a>` using Safari.

Seems that it does not always open the main Settings menu, but the last Settings sub-menu opened before clicking on the URL.

Same behavior with
`<a href="App-Prefs://prefs:any_string"> Settings menu </a>`

Comment: It's not working anymore on iOs 17.